# Join chat room with discussion history and receive messages

Tags: join, xmpp, openfire, strophe, chatroom

I use Strophe library to connect to an OpenFire XMPP server.

How can I receive the chat discussion history when I join a chat room.

I join chat room this way :

```
var o = {to:'roomName@conference.domain.com/youNick'}; 
var m = $pres(o); 
m.c('x', {xmlns : 'http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'}, null); 
connection.send(m.tree());
```

Comment: There is nothing to do to receive message history in XMPP. When you send the presence, the server may trigger latest message send. Can you please clarify your question about what is not working specifically ?

Comment: I have chat room "abc", one owner "A", two members "B", "C".
"A" and "B" joined the room "abc"and sending messages to the room. 
When member "C" sends his presence to abc room, he is not receiving the past messages of A and B's conversation.

Comment: ok, maybe there is a setting on Openfire to disable room history or there is a default room parameter set to 0. You should try getting the room settings to see what they are: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#roomconfig

Comment: Note that usually message room history is limited to a few messages (between 10-20 and 100).

Comment: I have enabled room history in the chat room settings in Openfire.
Default room history is set to 25 messages.

User "A" with admin role can retrieve the chat messages, but user "B" with member role is unable to retrieve the chat messages.

I have modified the role of user "C" to admin, then user "C" gets the chat history when joins the chat room.

Where can we set the roles privileges/ actions in Openfire admin console.

Thanks @MickaëlRémond

Comment: You can change the role directly in XMPP, using the XMPP protocol. For example, here is how to grant owner: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#grantowner

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get openfire chat room messages history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786034/how-to-get-openfire-chat-room-messages-history)