# How to get openfire chat room messages history

Tags: xmpp, openfire, message, strophe, multiuserchat

I use Strophe library to connect to an OpenFire XMPP server.

How can I receive the chat room messages history ?

```
var o = {to:'roomName@conference.domain.com/youNick'}; 
var m = $pres(o); 
m.c('x', {xmlns : 'http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'}, null); 
connection.send(m.tree());
```

I get only 25 messages when I join room. How to get past 25 message of the chat room ?

Answer (score 2):

You should add a `<history/>` element: https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter-managehistory.

```xml
<x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'>
    <history maxstanzas='100'/>
</x>
```

Comment: I have selected "Show Entire Chat History" in Group Chat-> Group Chat  Settings -> History Settings in Openfire Administrator console.

Even though I am getting only 25 messages from the chat room.
How to get entire chat history ?

Comment: Add `<history since='1970-01-01T00:00:00Z'/>` instead.

Comment: Can we send from date and to date to get chat room history ?

Comment: No, it always returns the newest messages. If you want something more flexible you should look at https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html.

Comment: Please post a new question if you have a different question from this one.